# Writing left join Query in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
select a.stakebuyinid , a.StakeBuyInValue  from StakeBuyInByStakeCategories  AS b 
left join StakeBuyIns AS a on b.stakebuyinid = a.stakebuyinid 
where b.GametypeId = 1 and b.StakeCategoryID = 3 and a.Currencyid = 1
```

above is my Simple SQL query i want to write in LINQ

I am using following LINQ query but Raise Error :-  "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

```
var query = (from v in db.StakeBuyInByStakeCategories.Where(x => x.GameTypeId == gametypeid && x.StakeCategoryId == stakecategoryid)
                        join u in db.StakeBuyIns.Where(y => y.CurrencyId == currencyid)
                               on v.StakeBuyInId equals u.StakeBuyInId into Temp
                           from vus in Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new {
                           vus.StakeBuyInId,
                           vus.StakeBuyInValue )
```

Comment: Okay. What did you try and where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assume 
`StakeBuyInByStakeCategoriesList as IEnumerable<StakeBuyInByStakeCategories>`
and `StakeBuyInsList as IEnumerable<StakeBuyIns>`

```
(from b in StakeBuyInByStakeCategoriesList 
 from a in StakeBuyInsList    
.Where(b.stakebuyinid equals a.stakebuyinid)
.DefaultIfEmpty()    
.Where( b.GametypeId == 1 and b.StakeCategoryID == 3 and a.Currencyid == 1)    
select new {Stakebuyinid=a.stakebuyinid, StakeBuyInValue=a.StakeBuyInValue}
```

Answer (score 0):

The int in your model should be an int?, since nullable return values are possible.